# iOS VoIP Push Notification stops automatically after 1-2 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, apple-push-notifications, voip

I have implemented the VoIP Push. everything works fine but when app recieves push, mobile starts ringing and just after 1-2 sec(the length of my .wav file) it stops.

**I want:** Sound should ring until user accept/reject the call.

**My solutions**

- I should place the lengthy sound so it keeps on
  ringing?
- Or i should send the Voip Push Again and again untill user cancels/attend call?
- After recieving push I should localy fire the push again and again.

Comment: I am having the same issue. This only happens when the app is at killed state. Testing in iOS 17. When app is opened or backgrounded, VOIP notification rings for awhile as expected. When the app is killed though, after like 2 seconds, the callKit notification/ringing disappears.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope once you receive pushkit payload, then you are scheduling local notification and local notification is having sound file.

Sound file plays on 2 things, length of sound file ( 5 / 10 / 15 Seconds ) or max upto 30 seconds.

So if your sound file is less then 30 seconds, then edit your sound file and make repetitive till 30 seconds.

If you want to play sound file for more than 30 seconds then either you have reschedule local notification with sound file at each 30 seconds till user accept call or resend push kit payload from back end.

After all this things still your sound file stops in 1/2 seconds, then do check may be your app is crashing in background or terminated state.

**Code**

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
        // Process the received push

        var arrTemp = [NSObject : AnyObject]()
        arrTemp = payload.dictionaryPayload

        let dict : Dictionary <String, AnyObject> = arrTemp["aps"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>


        if "IfUserHasLoggedInWithApp" // Check this flag then only proceed
        {                

            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background || UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive
            {

                if "CheckForIncomingCall" // Check this flag to know incoming call or something else
                {

                    var strTitle : String = dict["alertTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                    let strBody : String = dict["alertBody"] as? String ?? ""
                    strTitle = strTitle + "\n" + strBody

                    let notificationIncomingCall = UILocalNotification()

                    notificationIncomingCall.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
                    notificationIncomingCall.alertBody =  strTitle
                    notificationIncomingCall.alertAction = "Open"
                    notificationIncomingCall.soundName = "SoundFile.mp3"
                    notificationIncomingCall.category = dict["category"] as? String ?? ""

                    notificationIncomingCall.userInfo = "As per payload you receive"

                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notificationIncomingCall)

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //  something else
                    }

        }
    }

}
```

**Debug pushkit notification in terminated state**

- Put debug pointer on delegate methods
- Go to edit scheme
- Select run option then Launch -> Wait for executable to be launched
- Send push kit payload from back end
- Once you get payload on device
- it will automatically invoke and debug pointer will invoke at delegate methods.

[image]

You can refer some details here.

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Comment: No my app is not crashing

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Ok which method is more recommended from these "If you want to play sound file for more than 30 seconds then either you have reschedule local notification with sound file at each 30 seconds till user accept call or resend push kit payload from back end."

Comment: I had same scenario, we kept sending push kit payload at each 30 seconds from back end. This process will be like whatspp, skype and any other voip based app.

Comment: Thanks i get the idea

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue - where receiving VOIP push notification and the callKit notification would stop and disappear after a few seconds. So I started debugging the app from the killed state in the debugger by checking "Wait for the executable to be launched" option in the Run(debug) Xcode Edit scheme menu. And it turns out I had other totally irrelevant bug that crashed my app when my app got started after that few seconds when the Callkit notification appeared. I fixed that bug, and everything is working normally. So for you too, it is probably something else in your code crashing your app and at the same time stopping the callKit call notification.